# Abelian + normal $\implies$ central?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Here is the question, it is from a 2023 PhD qualifying exam at my university:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ of order 5. Prove that
> if $H$ contains an element not in the center of $G$, then $G$ has an element
> of order 2.

Here is my solution, but I am curious about the veracity of the highlighted part. It seems like cheating. I also don't see where I used anything specifically from the question for the highlighted part other than the fact that $H$ is of order 5 and hence equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

*Proof:*

Since $G$ is finite, its order will be a multiple of the subgroup, $H$, namely $5 \cdot k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N},  k > 0$. Now, $G$ will have an element of order $2$ exactly when it is an *even* multiple of $5$. To see this, note that every prime that divides a group's order defines a subgroup in that group. Furthermore, only when the prime's order divides the group's order can it be a subgroup, of course. This has two consequences.

- Groups of order $10, 20, 30, \ldots$ have a subgroup of order $2$ (and thus an element of order 2).
- Groups of order $5, 15, 25, 35, \ldots$ do *not* have an element of order $2$. Hence, if our conjecture is true, they must have a normal subgroup of size 5 contained in their center. This is what we'll show.

Every group of order $5 \cdot k$ where $k$ is positive will have a sub-group of order 5. Furthermore, every group of order 5 is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, which means it is Abelian and hence (as a subgroup) it is normal.

Let $x \in H$ and $y \in G$. Then we have:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{xy = yy^{-1} xy = y x y^{-1} y = yx.}
\end{equation*}
The middle step is because $H$ is Abelian so that once $y^{-1} x y \in H$ (by normalcy), we can commute the factors. This shows that
$xy = yx$ in $G$, i.e., that $x$ is in $Z(G)$, as required. \qed

Can we really "commute the factors" as I say? I'm just not sure. Thanks!

Comment: $A_4$ has a normal Abelian subgroup $V_4$, but is centerless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is incorrect.

Note that while $yxy^{-1}$ lies in $H$ and therefore commutes with every element of $H$, you are trying to commute it with $y$, but $y$ is assumed to be in $G$, not in $H$. So the equality $y(y^{-1}xy)=(y^{-1}xy)y$ need not hold.

The question in your title also has a negative answer. The smallest, easiest example is $S_3$, where the normal subgroup of order $3$ is of course abelian, but not central (since $Z(S_3)$ is trivial). Other examples can be found with the subgroups of order $4$ in $D_4$. For an example with a normal subgroup of order $5$, take the dihedral group of order $10$, in which the subgroup of order $5$ generated by the rotations is normal but not central.

In addition, you don't seem to be answering the question! Unless it is your contention that it is impossible for a group to have a normal subgroup of order $5$ unless that subgroup lies in the center.

To actually answer the question, consider the action of $G$ on $H$ by conjugation. This yields a morphism $G\to\mathrm{Aut}(H)$; and since $H$ is cyclic of order $5$, you know that $H$ lies in the kernel of that map, and that $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ has order $4$. If we are assuming that $H$ has a non-central element, that means that the action is not trivial, so the image of $G$ is not trivial. That means that the image has order $2$ or $4$, which tells you that the order of $G$ is even.

Comment: Thanks! Now, though, I have to try to understand your last paragraph, lol. You say that $H \subseteq Ker(\xi)$ where $\xi : G \rightarrow Aut(H)$ is given by $\xi(g) = gHg^{-1}$. (At least, I _think_ that's what you said.) Why is $\xi(H) = \{ e \}$ ($e$ being the identity)? Wouldn't $\xi(H) = H$?

Comment: @BlueGhost: No, $\xi(g)$ is an automorphism of $H$, so it is a (bijective) homomorphism $\xi(g)\colon H\to H$, not a subgroup of $G$; for each $h\in H$, $\xi(g)(h) = ghg^{-1}$. Since $H$ is abelian, if $g\in H$ then $\xi(g)(h) = ghg^{-1}=gg^{-1}h=h$, so $\xi(g)$ is the identity automorphism, and therefore $g$ lies in the kernel of $\xi$ (since the identity automorphism is the identity element of $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$. This is a standard mapping whenever you have $N\triangleleft G$.

Answer (score 5):

$H$ is normal, so it can be written as the set-theoretical disjoint union of $G$-conjugacy classes. One of these is $\{1\}$ and we are left with $4$ elements. Since $H \cap Z(G)=1$ no further singletons can arise, so either the cardinalities of the other $ G$-conjugacy classes are $2+2$ or $4$. Either way, $2$ divides the cardinality and on its turn this number divides $|G|$. Hence $|G|$ must be even and we finish with an appeal to Cauchy's Theorem.